# Rails 3.1 Devise How To Change Flash Message CSS From notice to success?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

Rails 3.1 and Devise 1.5 question.

I'm using the following code to display flash messages in my layout:

```
    <% flash.each do |key, message| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, message, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
    <% end %>
```

I'd like to change the css class for some of my confirmation messages from notice to success, but I don't know where to override or change the key because I don't know where it's set.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You can edit the text of devise flash messages by enabling i18n and modifying the default locale. But I don't think you can easily change if they are added as notice or success... https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml . A very dirty way would be to add html in the messages, and modify your css to take that into account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way to do this is to edit the devise controllers.

When you install Devise through the normal installation I don't think it install the controllers (at least it didn't for me).

So first you should manually add the controller files and put them into your project in the same location: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise

Once you have the files in your project, go to the "sessions_controller.rb" file.

One lines 16 & 25, you should see the code:

```
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_in
```

and

```
set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out
```

You just need to change ":notice" to ":success"

Hope that works!

Comment: My project throws error on the lines I changed.  Is there anything else you need to do other than put the files in a folder called devise under the controllers folder?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem because I'm using the bootstrap-sass gem which uses a whole different class structure for flash messages. I took the route of solving this with sass rather than messing with devise at all (sass inheritance is awesome:).

So, I render the flash messages in `app/view/layouts/application.html.haml`:

```
%div.container
  - flash.each do |key, value|
    = content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-dismisable alert-#{key}")
```

And, I add a simple rule to `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss` to get Devise's flash messages working:

```
/* Style Devise Flash messages like Bootstrap */
.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}
```

That's it! now `flash[:alert]` is styled just like bootstrap's `flash[:warning]`.

Answer (score 0):

The css class is being set by the `:class` argument. To add a class of `notice` (or `success`, etc.), just change your call to the following:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, message, :class => "flash #{key} notice") %>
```

Comment: This would add a notice class to every flash message, which is not what he wants.