# devise 5: How do I modify the Flash messages from Devise to match my css for flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, flash-message

I'm running the latest version of devise 5 in my Rails 5.1 application. I have the following CSS code for flash messages in my stylesheet.

```
div.alert.alert-danger, .alert-danger { background-color: #ff0000; }
div.alert.alert-info, .alert-info { background-color: #99d7ea; }
div.alert.alert-success, .alert-success { background-color: #a3da2f; }
div.alert.alert-warning , .alert-warning { background-color: #e6c856; }
```

The original code only had the first class. It works just fine. After reading some older answers regarding this I added the second one attempting to change the css for the flash messages in devise. The messages from devise show up with my default font size and color but a transparent background. I want them to match what I have defined for my flash messages. The ones I issue use my defined CSS.

Where/how can I override the devise CSS for flash messages to match mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that a part of my problem was that I need to know what devise flash types were. From this link I only found two: alert and notice.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb#L10

Neither of these are used in rails 5. They are danger, info, success and warning. I decided to match the css for alert like danger and notice like success. From this link I found a 4 year old answer that still works with the current version of devise.

[Rails 3.1 Devise How To Change Flash Message CSS From notice to success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387135/rails-3-1-devise-how-to-change-flash-message-css-from-notice-to-success)

I added the following two statements in my stylesheet and now all messages from Devise appear like my other flash messages.

```
.alert-alert { @extend .alert-warning; }
.alert-notice { @extend .alert-success; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably really want to modify the markup to match your flash message structure.

The `devise_error_messages!` [method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb) defines the markup for devise error messages. You can override that method in your `ApplicationHelper` to accommodate the markup you need.

Comment: [Devise] `DeviseHelper#devise_error_messages!` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

Devise now uses a partial under "devise/shared/error_messages" to display
error messages by default, and make them easier to customize. Update your
views changing calls from:

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

to:

```
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
```

To start customizing how errors are displayed, you can copy the partial
from devise to your `app/views` folder. Alternatively, you can run
`rails g devise:views` which will copy all of them again to your app.

How to edit CSS: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap#css-for-flash-messages (Rails 4 and Devise 3)